# Are cash gifts from a former employer taxable in Canada?

Tags: taxes, canada, gift-tax

I was previously employed by an elderly couple providing in-home care for several years.  The husband passed away a number of years ago, while the wife passed away last year.  Obviously, as the couple both passed away, my employment terminated.

The estate has been settled, and I am being gifted money from a family member of the couple.  It has been made clear to me that this is not an inheritance, but a gift.  The family member facilitating the gift was previously responsible for providing me with my paystubs, T4 etc.

Under these circumstances, where the family was my previous (but not current..) employer, am I required to pay taxes on the gift?

Comment: I know in the States you're exempt from paying taxes on gifts under $15,000 (in 2019). I bet it's similar in Canada.

Comment: A tricky question!